# Joining 2 text files in least amount of time

Tags: performance, unix, join, text

We have 2 text files (`|` delimited) with a common column to tie them. One text file measures close to 45G(~ 125 million rows) and the other is smaller at 7GB.

We have tried using the [join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28Unix%29) command in Linux. The performance seemed great to me(took approx. 90 mins to complete the merge). I wanted to find if there is any other tool/data structure that can speed up the merge even faster. Though the `join` command is very fast, we would have to run this process(i.e. merging 2 files) 70 times. Obviously this works out to 100 hours of processing.

Comment: Have you tried using cat? cat file1 file2 > file3

Comment: @PaulDardeau: How can `cat` join 2 files using a common column? I believe it can only append contents

Comment: Yep, sorry I missed that part of your question!

Comment: but doing the `cat` test would be a good baseline for what you could possible expect for speed. My guess is that `join` is almost as fast as `cat`, and you'll spend more time looking for an alternate solution that you could save in processing time. The only thing I can think is that if you don't need all the columns in your bigger file, use the `join -o 1.3 2.1  ....` output option to reduce the amt of data being written to disk. `join` is going to be about as good as you can do, so just best to set expecations of 100 hrs, and kick it off! (you're data is pre-sorted, right?!) . Good luck.!

Comment: @shellter: Yes the data is pre-sorted, thank you for your feedback!